# Undefined Variable error in ansible for /etc/ansible/hosts varaiables

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have two VMs one as ansible control machine and running playbook to perform action on second vm.

Following are files on ansible control machine

/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

```
inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
```

/etc/ansible/hosts

```
# My nodes
[my-group]
my1-node ansible_user=imran DB_SERVER=10.136.10.49 DB_USER=mydbusr
```

I tried following two ways to access variables but no success, but if i provide with command line like -e DB_SERVER=10.136.10.49. its working

myplaybook

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg:
          - "Database server {{DB_SERVER}}"
          - "Database Username  {{  hostvars['DB_USER'] }}"
```

Above is producing error

Update:
I also run with verbose and its saying so its pointing to correct config, as i read due to vagrant sometime configuration is not pointed correctly.

```
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
```

Comment: can you say what is the error ?

Comment: `hostvars['DB_USER']` makes no sense, `hostvars` contains keys with host names, not variables. For `DB_SERVER` there is no reason to produce an error with the configuration you posted.

Comment: @tux while printing they are not showing any value. if i cast to int its saying undefined variable.

Comment: @techraf any clue to further debug as i tried every possible option.

Comment: "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'DB_SERVER' is undefined"

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the `hostvars` magic variables array, you should use the below syntax:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg:
          - "Database server {{DB_SERVER}}"
          - "Database Username  {{  hostvars[inventory_hostname]['DB_USER'] }}"
```

`{{DB_SERVER}}` should work, ansible knows how to resolve it to the value you defined in the inventory file.

hope it helps.